# How to print a 2-D array in java without taking a new line for every group of elements? i.e to represent a 7x7 board game

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to print a 2-d array of integers thats to represent a 7x7 board game.  I have already populated the array with 0's and I'm trying to print it using a nested for loop:

```
public void showBoard(){

    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        System.out.println("\n");
        for(int j =0; j < 7; j++){
            System.out.println(board[i][j]);    
        }
    }

}
```

the problem is after every ith element it takes a new line so my output is as follows (I attached an image as it wasn't formating properly when I typed it):

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yy9oP.png)

can anyone suggest a way to print it to represent a board? e.g.

```
0000000
0000000
0000000
0000000
0000000
0000000
0000000
```

Comment: use System.out.print instead of println

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [`System.out.print(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print-java.lang.String-) instead of [`System.out.println(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.String-) :-)

`println(…)` always appends a newline after the text you pass as argument, as the Javadoc says:

> Prints a String and then terminate the line. This method behaves as though it invokes [print(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print-java.lang.String-) and then [println()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println--).